# returning null when implementing Geocoder

Tags: android, google-geocoder

I'm trying to find the address(location) using Geocoder.

I have the following code:

```
double lat = (double) (coord.getLat() * (1e-6));
double lon = (double) (coord.getLon() * (1e-6));
try { 
    List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon,1);

    if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
        Address address = list.get(0);
        result = address.getAddressLine(0) + ", "
            + address.getLocality();
    }
System.out.println("adresa returnata folosind geocoder:"
                + result);
}
```

The data that I pass to geocoder is in this format:

2.449548
48.950518

But when trying to `println()` the first address returned by Geocoder it returns null. This is how my logcat looks like:

> reverseGeocode()`: no feature in
>   GLocation

And my `System.out.println()` displays `:null`. I have internet acces and also internet permssion added to my manifest file. Does someone know what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: where do you initiate the geocoder variable?

Comment: have you tried different coordinates? The ones you listed show up as in the ocean in google maps, with no addresses listed nearby.

Comment: Yes,I have a KML of coordinates that are retrieved and then passed to the constructor!

Comment: @Franziskus....This is how I initiate the Geocoder:Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);

Answer (score 1):

As Geobits said, your coordinates belong to place in the Arabian Sea. You cant get an Address from there, so your list is empty and your result is null.

Comment: I wonder why you did not get a upvote and a accept answer for this ?